# how to print char in multiple times in c++

Tags: c++, loops

2*

4**

6***

need to output above pattern
the code given below I have tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main (){
string star = "*";
int a=2;
while(a<=6){
    cout<<a<<star*(a/2)<<endl;
    a+=2;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think that `star*(a/2)` should do?? You have to write a loop or initialize a `std::string` with `a/2` `'*'` characters to get that working.

Comment: Your logic to count number of stars that should get printed is correct. But the method to print those many stars is not correct. How would you print a single star?

Comment: @user0042 - If the OP is coming from a language like Python, Javascript or Perl? Easy mistake to make.

Comment: `std::string` has a constructor taking a single character and a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main (){
   int a=2;
   while(a<=6){
       cout<< a << std::string((a/2),'*') <<endl;
                // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       a+=2;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

int main () {
    for(auto i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        std::cout << i*2 << std::string(i,'*') << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a second loop to handle the stars.

```
cout<<a;
for (int i = 0; i < a/2; i++)
    cout<<'*';
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: need to use while loop

Comment: @gihansalith then use the idea and write your own loop using while

Answer (score 0):

Your code should produce a compilation error, like this:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:10:22: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' and 'int')
         cout<<a<<star*(a/2)<<endl;
                  ~~~~^~~~~~
```

since `star` is a string and `a` an integer, thus you cannot do what you wish to achieve.

Instead, you could do it without using `std::string`, but a single character instead. Then use a loop to print stars as many times as needed (you seem to know how many times the loop should execute already).

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){
    char star = '*';
    int i, a = 2;
    while(a <= 6) {
        cout << a;
        i = 0;
        while(i++ < a/2)
            cout<< star;
        cout << endl;
        a+=2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2*
4**
6***
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(a <= 6){

 cout<<a;

 int c = 0;
 int b = a/2;

 while(c < b){

  cout<<star<<endl;
  c++;

 }
a=+2;
}
```

This is just as simple as i can answer. Hope you can get the idea.